# Splitting String to produce desired array?

Tags: java, regex, arrays, split

Say I have the text: aabbaaccddaaee. I need to split the string to produce the array: ["aa", "aa", "aa"]. How would I accomplish this?

**EDIT**:
To clear things up, I have the user enter `{blocked-users(user1|user2|user3)}`, and I need to find all of the occurrences of `{blocked-users(.*)}` and get an array of them so I can parse the users that they inputted.

Comment: By using the proper regular expression. What have you tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: You need to specify why should the output be `["aa","aa","aa"]` for that particular string.

Comment: @jitendra - I suspect it's homework because it's a very simple problem that you wouldn't ever find in the real world.

Comment: @jitendra
The user inputs a string into the config, such at this:
{blocked-users(user1|user2|user3)}
I have everything working besides getting the string inside the brackets.

Comment: @user2125177 It still isn't clear from your comment what exactly are you trying to do. Can you edit your question and explain your scenario properly. Otherwise, you are likely to invite more downvotes!

Comment: @BrianRoach From OP's comment it seems it isn't a homework but he trivialized his problem by asking it in improper manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( "aabbaaccddaaee".split("[^a]+") ) );
// [aa, aa, aa]
```

To get all blocked users you could compile the pattern

```
"\\{blocked-users\\(([^)]+)\\)\\}"
```

and use `find` in a loop, splitting the capture group `()` on `|` to produce an array of blocked users for each match, i.e. `group(1).split("\\|")`.